# Avoid displaying feature in the duplicate maps on left/right side dragging in openlayers?

Tags: angular6, openlayers-3

I created feature to display in some co-ordinates near India. So I drag the map to left/right side there also we can see India again with that feature. I decide to display feature only once. Please suggest me.

Comment: Specify `wrapX: false` on your vector source(s)

Answer (score 0):

Specify wrapX: false on your vector source(s)